# KENDO UI ASPNET Multiple editorTemplate in grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am currently having a problem in my kendo grids. I have multiple columns who are type of decimal. The problem is when I want to use numerictextBox for those columns, I should create n editor template for n columns because of the .Name("") attribute of the numericTextBox.

Is there any way to bind the numericTextBox by using only one generic template ? Or how can I avoid creating multiple editorTemplate file in which only the name attribute is varying ?

Thanks for your help.

Here is my grid:

```
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<myModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Events(events =>
{
    events.Save("onSaveObject");
})
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(r => r.NAME).Title("Name");
    columns.Bound(r => r.SIZE).Title("SIZE").EditorTemplateName("SIZEEditor");
    columns.Bound(r => r.SIZE1).Title("SIZE1").EditorTemplateName("SIZE1Editor");
    columns.Bound(r => r.SIZE2).Title("SIZE1").EditorTemplateName("SIZE2Editor");
    columns.Bound(r => r.SIZE3).Title("SIZE1").EditorTemplateName("SIZE3Editor");
    columns.Bound(r => r.SIZE4).Title("SIZE1").EditorTemplateName("SIZE4Editor");
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
})
..


%>

SIZEEditor.ascx

<%: Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
    .Name("SIZE")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { value = "#=SIZE #" })
    .Format("{0:n1}")
    .Culture("fr-FR")
    .Min(0)
    .Max(500)
    .Decimals(1)
%>

SIZE1Editor.ascx

<%: Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
    .Name("SIZE1")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { value = "#=SIZE1 #" })
    .Format("{0:n1}")
    .Culture("fr-FR")
    .Min(0)
    .Max(500)
    .Decimals(1)
%>

SIZE2Editor.ascx

<%: Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
    .Name("SIZE2")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { value = "#=SIZE2 #" })
    .Format("{0:n1}")
    .Culture("fr-FR")
    .Min(0)
    .Max(500)
    .Decimals(1)
%>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your editor template specify its name, so it will render static name for input element instead of dynamic name.

change your editor template like this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<decimal?>" %>
<%: Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m)
    .Format("{0:n1}")
    .Culture("fr-FR")
    .Min(0)
    .Max(500)
    .Decimals(1)
%>
```

Comment: You mean this?   <%: Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<decimal?>(m => m)
                    Format("{0:n2}")
                    .Culture("fr-FR")
                    .Min(0)
                    .Max(100000)
                    .Decimals(2)
%>     it says "can not convert implicitly object to decimal.....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dio Dirza for your help. This did the trick. I only changed the "Inherits" value of the template.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<decimal?>" %>

<%: Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m=>m)
    .Format("{0:n2}")
    .Culture("fr-FR")
    .Min(-50)
    .Max(100000)
    .Decimals(2)
%>
```